# Слаги получают добавку "-2", из-за того, что на сайт загружены картинки с таким же названием

Tags: wordpress, slug

**Проблема:**
При создании страницы задаю слаг (slug) из короткого слова вида "mouse", "rat" и т.п.
При сохранении, WordPress меняет слаги на "mouse-2", "rat-2".

Сайт свежеустановленный, я проверил все страницы и записи - страниц и записей с такими названиями () точно не существует.

**Причина**
На сайт загружены фотографии с такими названиями ("mouse.png", "rat.png"), при удалении этих файлов из медиабиблиотеки, проблема исчезает. То есть для решения проблемы мне надо удалить все файлы с такими названиями, переименовать исходники и загрузить их заново.

**Вопрос**
Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему, не удаляя и переименовывая файлы изображений?

Comment: Переименуй слаг изображений

Comment: Подскжи как? В админке нет слагов изображений. Кроме того как я описал - скачать файл и переименовать его название - я не знаю способа.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/vsCgdht.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не надо с этим ничего делать. WordPress создаёт уникальный слаг специально.

Можно, конечно, использовать фильтр

```
    /**
     * Filters the unique post slug.
     *
     * @since 3.3.0
     *
     * @param string $slug          The post slug.
     * @param int    $post_ID       Post ID.
     * @param string $post_status   The post status.
     * @param string $post_type     Post type.
     * @param int    $post_parent   Post parent ID
     * @param string $original_slug The original post slug.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug', $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug );
```

в функции ядра `wp_unique_post_slug()`. Но последствия в админке могут быть непредсказуемые.